# UNIX - Moving a deleted file back to it's original directory

Tags: unix, if-statement, rm, mv

All I want to do is move a file from my created recycle bin to it's own original path.

My code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

restore ()
{
  base=`basename $restore_file | cut -d"_" -f1`
  echo "Your file $base has been restored"
  mv deleted/$restore_file /$HOME/$base
}

restore_file=$1

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "You have not entered a file"
elif [ -e deleted/$restore_file ]
then
  restore
  grep -v $(basename $restore_file) $HOME/.restore.info >> $HOME/.restore.inf o.tmp
  cp $HOME/.restore.info.tmp $HOME/.restore.info
  rm $HOME/.restore.info.tmp
else
  echo "Your file "$restore_file" does not exist"
fi
```

I'm sure the error is in on line 7, just not sure how to rewrite. Any ideas?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I would start deleting lines from the second part.  Strip the script down to its essence.  That will help.

Comment: Also, the way you've currently written your script, it'll only work if you run it from the parent directory of the `deleted` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to put a full path in before `deleted`?

You don't need the slash before `$HOME`, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I have to somehow pull the directory from where the file was deleted, and append that file to the end of it in order to move it back to it's original location. I'm sure there's a simple way to do it but I have not come across any solution

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Is `deleted` a subdirectory of the original location of the file?  In that case, it seems to me that either you have to record that directory somewhere, or the user has to provide it either as an argument, or by cd'ing to the right location first.

Comment: deleted is a subdirectory where all my deleted files are being sent to. $HOME/deleted. The user calls my restore function in order to pull that deleted file out of $HOME/deleted, and back to it's original directory.

Comment: OK, so why not put `$HOME/` before `deleted` in line 7?

Comment: I think that would be redundant to say, deleted/$base = $HOME/deleted/$base I believe

Comment: If that path begins with a directory name and not a slash, then it's relative to whatever directory the script is executed relative to.  (Or to whatever directory another script invoking this one is relative to.)  `mv this/that $HOME/overthere` will try to find the file named `that` in a directory `this` under the directory I'm in.  If I'm in my `$HOME/anotherdir` directory, `mv` will look for `$HOME/anotherdir/this/that`.  If I wanted it to find `$HOME/this/that`, I should `mv`ed that, or used an explicit path such as in `mv /Users/joe/this/that /Users/joe/anotherdir`.